# Matching Id's And Merging Into Target With Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table: AttackTable.dbo

```
| attackId | id       | name         |damage |
|----------|----------|--------------|-------|
| 1        | base1-8  | Seismic Toss |60     |
| 2        | base1-9  | Thunder Wave |30     |
| 3        | base1-9  | Self-Destruct|80     |
| 4        | base1-10 | Psychic      |10+    |
| 5        | base1-10 | Barrier      |0      |
```

I have been using this code to do the rest of my work:

```
UPDATE P
SET 
    [id] = C.[id],
    [subtypes] = C.[subtypes],
    [types] = C.[types],
    [evolvesFrom] = C.[evolvesFrom],
    [evolvesTo] = C.[evolvesTo],
    [retreatCost] = C.[retreatCost],
    [nationalPokedexNumbers] = C.[nationalPokedexNumbers]
FROM PokeId AS P
JOIN PokemonMisc AS C ON P.[id] = C.[id];
```

However, since this table is different - I've run into a problem. I'm not too good at this computer stuff so I'd appreciate a hand.

**My Goal is to Move this data to Master.Dbo.**

Master DBO has all [id]'s listed and does not contain duplicates, I want a code that allows me to store the value of `AttackTable([name])` to `MASTER([attackName1])` according to matching [id].
However, since I can't allow duplicate id values in `Master`, if `Master([attackName1])` already stores data, then this needs to go into `Master([attackName2])` - same goes to `Master([damage1])` and `Master([damage2])`.

**My expected outcome is this:**

Master.dbo

```
| id       | attackName1  | attackName2 | damage1| damage2  |
|----------|--------------|-------------|--------|----------|
| base1-8  | Seismic Toss |             | 60     |          |
| base1-9  | Thunder Wave |Self-Destruct| 30     |80        |
| base1-10 | Psychic      |  Barrier    | 10+    |0         |
```

Can anyone successfully help me? This is my last step.

I have tried making some statements similar to `IF MASTER([attackName1] == !null) THEN AttackTable([name])--> MASTER.([attackName2])`...

Comment: ok, sorry 'bout that Dale. First post after many years of lurking.

Comment: Your `Master` table isn't very normalized. there are cases where it's worth saving your data in a denormalized table, but that doesn't strike me as one of them. Are you sure you want this table structure?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I believe I can use the id as a key of some sort. I would prefer to keep this table structure in Master.dbo. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE Master
SET
  attackName1 = CTE.attackName1,
  attackName2 = NULLIF(CTE.attackName2, CTE.attackName1),
  attackDamage1 = CTE.attackDamage1,
  attackDamage2 = NULLIF(CTE.attackDamage2, CTE.attackDamage1)
FROM Master
JOIN (
  SELECT id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY attackId) As attackName1,
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY attackId DESC) As attackName2,
       FIRST_VALUE(damage) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY attackId) As attackDamage1,
       FIRST_VALUE(damage) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY attackId DESC) As attackDamage2
  FROM AttackTable
) AS CTE
ON Master.id = CTE.id;
```

Comment: This appears to be a response to @Zoher's request for more code. If so, this should be an edit to your original question, since it doesn't provide an answer.

Comment: @JeremyCaney That was the solution, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you insist you want your data in a denormalized table, Here's how I would do it.

First, create and populate sample data and target tables (**Please** save us this step in your future questions):

```
CREATE TABLE AttackTable (
    [attackId] int, 
    [id] varchar(10), 
    [name] varchar(14), 
    [damage] varchar(7)
);
    
INSERT INTO AttackTable ([attackId], [id], [name], [damage]) VALUES
(1, 'base1-8', 'Seismic Toss', '60'),
(2, 'base1-9', 'Thunder Wave', '30'),
(3, 'base1-9', 'Self-Destruct', '80'),
(4, 'base1-10', 'Psychic', '10+'),
(5, 'base1-10', 'Barrier', '0');

CREATE TABLE [Master] (
    [id] varchar(8), 
    [attackName1] varchar(12), 
    [attackName2] varchar(13), 
    [damage1] varchar(3), 
    [damage2]  varchar(3)
);
```

Use a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with [`First_value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) window function to get the first and last values of `name` and `damage` for each `id`, based on the order of `attackId`. Then, use `distinct` and `nullif` to get the values for `attackName2` and `damage2` - and insert these records to the master table:

```
WITH CTE AS
(  
SELECT Id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY attackId) As AttackName1,
       FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY attackId DESC) As AttackName2,
       FIRST_VALUE(damage) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY attackId) As damage1,
       FIRST_VALUE(damage) OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY attackId DESC) As damage2
FROM AttackTable
)
  
INSERT INTO Master (id, attackName1, attackName2, damage1, damage2)
SELECT DISTINCT Id,
  AttackName1, 
  NULLIF(AttackName2, AttackName1) As AttackName2, 
  damage1,
  NULLIF(damage2, damage1) As damage2
FROM CTE
```

Finnaly, select from `Master` to see if we got the results as expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM Master
ORDER BY LEN(id), id
```

Results:

```
id          attackName1     attackName2     damage1 damage2
base1-8     Seismic Toss    null            60      null
base1-9     Thunder Wave    Self-Destruct   30      80
base1-10    Psychic         Barrier         10+     0
```

You can see a live demo on [<kbd>db<>fiddle</kbd>](https://dbfiddle.uk/-5LTuvDO)

Comment: Thank You Zohar, I have come a long way since last night trying to get a hold of this and your code seems to make perfect sense to me, yet returns a new set of [id] in Master.dbo with all of the attacks and isn't correctly matching them to their respective Id's. I tested your example code in fiddle and it worked fine, so thank you for that. Yet no avail in implementation, I have ensured matching column names and types. I also still have a hard time understanding the use of "Id" as opposed to the column name; '[id]'.

Comment: Well I can only test the sample data you've provided, perhaps edit you question to include the problematic rows might help us to help you